# SQL date logic to fetch the values

Tags: mysql, sql, putty

**Need SQL logic**

1. If i enter sys date as 15th it has to fetch the values from 1-15th.
2. if i enter date as following month 2nd it has to fetch from 15th to
   2nd.

**Example**

```
 Sys date April 15th - April 1 to April 15th date values needs to be fetch.
 Sys date May 2nd - April 15th to May 2nd date values needs to be fetch.
```

Please suggest

Comment: MySQL or Oracle or both?

Comment: my sql only.. ppl in oracle also may know it right?

Comment: Oracle and MySQL RDBMS's have quite different syntax, better to pick one. Also, you're not quite making it clear what would happen on, for example, May 12th if you did the select. Same as May 2 or 14 days back from May 12?

Answer (score 0):

So as a general methodology you'd need a function to return the day number in the month, and two case statements to each return a particular date as a boundary. Date arithmetic is used to convert the system date to the upper and lower boundaries required, so on Oracle you'd use Trunc(sysdate,'mm') and add_months(...,n) and add days on as integers.

Date functions are here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions001.htm

Can't help you with MySQL functions -- doubtless they're documented somewhere.

you'll end up with ...

```
date_col > case <function on sysdate>
             when < 15 then <function for lower bound case 1>
             when < 15 then <function for lower bound case 2>
           end and
date_col < case <function on sysdate>
             when < 15 then <function for upper bound case 1>
             when < 15 then <function for upper bound case 2>
           end and
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using DAYOFWEEK() and MONTH() functions to determine the start and end dates of the query.

```
SET @day = DAYOFMONTH(<date entered>)
SET @month = MONTH(<date entered>)

IF @month > MONTH(NOW()) AND @day = 2 THEN
    SET @start_date = DATE_SUB(<date entered>, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 13 DAY
    SET @end_date = <date entered>
ELSEIF @month = MONTH(NOW()) AND @day = 15 THEN    
    SET @start_date = DATE_SUB(<date entered>, INTERVAL 14 DAY)
    SET @end_date = <date entered>
END IF;

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDate BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
```

Comment: I suspect you mean [`DAYOFMONTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth)?